# Absolute value equation infinite solutions

Tags: absolute-value

$$|3-x|+4x=5|2+x|-13$$

One of the solutions is $[3,\infty)$

I'm not familiar with interval solutions for absolute equations.

How to solve for this interval?

Comment: I don't think that interval can be a solution: you wrote **an equation**,  *not an inequality* ...

Comment: @DonAntonio One simple example is $|x-1| + |x+1| = 2$. All $x\in[-1,1]$ are solutions.

Comment: @DonAntonio  No...every $x$ in that interval is a solution.  Indeed, in that range $|3-x|=x-3$ and $|2+x|=2+x$ so the equation reads $x-3+4x=10+5x-13$ which is true.

Comment: @peterwhy Excellent point, thanks.

Comment: @lulu Excellent comment, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to do is to notice that if $x$ is large and positive, then
$|3-x|$ is the same as $x-3$, so the equation becomes
$$
(x-3)+4x = 5(x+2) -13 \\
5x-3 = 5x -3
$$ 
and so any time $x$ is that large, the equation is automatically true.  How large is "that large"?

Well, as long as $x\geq 3$ the essential property that $|3-x| = x-3$ holds. So the equation is autmatically satisfied for $x\geq 3$, that is, on the intervale $[3,+\infty)$.

(By the way, the square brace on the left means $x$ is greater than or equal to $3$; the parenthesis on the right means $x < \infty$.

If $x<3$ then $|3-x| = 3-x$ and if $x \geq -2$  the equation becomes
$$
(3-x)+4x = 5(x+2)-13\\
3x+3 = 5x -3 \\
x=3
$$
and that adds nothing new.  But if $x<-2$ the equation becomes
$$
(3-x)+4x = -5(x+2)-13\\
3x+3 = -5x -23 \\
8x=-26 \\
x= -\frac{13}{4}
$$
and that is an isolated additional solution:
$$
|3-(-\frac{13}{4})| +4(-\frac{13}{4})= \frac{25}{4}-13= -\frac{27}{4}\\
5|2+(-\frac{13}{4})|-13 = 5(\frac54)-13 = -\frac{27}{4}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Do case work lucky guess start with $3-x\geq 0$ then $|3-x|=x-3$ and $|2+x|=2+x$ so
$$x-3+4x=10+5x-13\\5x=5x\\0=0$$
Since $0=0$ is always true we have that for each $x\geq 3$ you have a solution.
If for example you've got $1=2$ which is always false you wouldn't have any solutions.

For other solution check the other two cases $-2<x<3$ and $x\leq -2$

Comment: I get it now, every time the solution is an identity, ex. 5=5, it means that all x-es from the defined intervals are the solutions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user455156 Exactly, no problem.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve a problem like this is by graphing both sides of the equation.

You can do this in, for example, Desmos [**here**](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/9bfrpo902z). An image of the linked graph, showing that the two lines coincide for $x \geq 3$ (and showing that they coincidence at one other $x$-value, too):

[image]

Another way to solve these sorts of problems is by analyzing different cases: I see now that **kingW3** has already provided an answer in this direction, so I'll curtail my response here.